# Pandas- merge two columns (one is list, one is string)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

Want to merge two columns, one column is string, the other column is lists of strings, want to append the string to the list of the other, for example:

```
input: 
A   B    
5 [1,2]
2 [3,4]

return:
A  B     C
5 [1,2]  [1,2,5]
2 [3,4]  [3,4,2]
```

Tried to use apply but not how to deal with columns with different types

Answer (score 3):

Using `DataFrame.apply`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['5', '2'], 'B': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]})
>>> df['C'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['B'] + [r['A']], axis=1)
>>> df
   A       B          C
0  5  [1, 2]  [1, 2, 5]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4, 2]
```

---

```
>>> df['C'] = df['B'] + df['A'].apply(lambda x: [x])
>>> df
   A       B          C
0  5  [1, 2]  [1, 2, 5]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4, 2]
```

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE, You're right. I updated the answer to delete the redundant `int` call. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Oops! I removed the comment. Thanks!

Comment: Applying with lambda is usually very slow.

Comment: @Bharathshetty, I know. I couldn't think of `df['A'].apply(list)` as you did.

Comment: Oh no I came up with the same solution not fair.

Comment: @Bharathshetty, I updated the answer to include modified version of yours.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['C']=[[x[0]] + x[1] for x in df.values.tolist()]
df
Out[435]: 
   A       B          C
0  5  [1, 2]  [5, 1, 2]
1  2  [3, 4]  [2, 3, 4]
```

If using `apply`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['523', '212'], 'B': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]})

df.A.apply(lambda x : [x])+df.B
Out[465]: 
0    [523, 1, 2]
1    [212, 3, 4]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Explicit `int` conversion required: `[[int(r[0])] + r[1] for r in df.values.tolist()]`

Comment: I upvoted becuase of speed of list comprehension. One silly error made me lose the addition of columns :(

Comment: @falsetru if you have time , can you help me why `[x[1].append(x[0]) for x in df.values.tolist()]` does not work ?  thanks

Comment: @Wen, `list.append` appends in-place, and does not return new value; `None`. Try `[x[1] + [x[0]] for x in df.values.tolist()]`

Comment: @Wen, No problem. Happy python programming!

Comment: @falsetru I am still new to python , It is hard convert my mind from `R` to `python`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(C=[[x, y, z] for x, (y, z) in zip(df.A, df.B)])

   A       B          C
0  5  [1, 2]  [5, 1, 2]
1  2  [3, 4]  [2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Sir if df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['5', '2'], 'B': [[1, 2,6], [3, 4,7]]})?